# LM317 to create constant current of 2mA?

Tags: current, lm317, constant-current, voltage-regulator

I have a circuit where I want to have a constant current of 2mA through a variable resistor.  I've been told that I could probably use a LM317 as a current regulator, with one resistor on the ouput.  But I've read some places that the LM317 takes minimum 5-10mA load to function correctly.

How can I achieve a constant current output of 2mA when I don't know the resistance of the variable resistor?

The input voltage is about 2.755V. Output voltage doesn't matter, just the current.

Here's an image to my feeble attempt at a schematic:
[image]

Comment: Don't trust "some places": read the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf)

Comment: @hesadanza It might be helpful for you to explain why you need a 2mA limit. This is very low and must be some rare circumstance that you have. There might be a better way to do what you are needing to do.

Comment: What does this circuit do?  What is it's output?  Limiting the output current could be as simple as adding a series resistor, but that depends on details.  Show the schematic of the output section and explain how this output signal is intended to be used.

Comment: I've tried using resistors, but the input voltage can vary a little, as well as the resistance of the system, which is why I wanted to use a current regulator of some sort.

Comment: @Kellenjb I need constant current.  It's a very simple circuit, with the output basically going through a single variable resistor (which is hard to tell the resistance of beforehand).

Comment: An eg LM324 quad opamp could be used for this as the opamp can source more than 2 mA.

Comment: What accuracy do you need over what voltage range? @Kellenjb, sometimes I find it mildly frustrating that people question a reasonable spec. We use vacuum gauges all over our system which require a fixed current source to be driven through a resistor with voltage being the feddback of gas level. I think the issue here is not what it is needed for but more details about the 2mA required current. Do we need 1% accuracy over a .01% load variance or the other way around.

Comment: I just tried making current source with LM317. I can set current to 2mA no problem. But setting yet smaller current is problematic. I plugged 10k pot hoping to regulate current down to 0.1 mA. However current goes down to some 0.8 A and no less.

Comment: LM317 is a faster than LM334!!

Comment: Actually, the output voltage does matter and you need to tell us where the "output" is in your circuit. If it's the voltage across the resistor then the largest possible output voltage dictates the maximum voltage across the current source, an extremely important parameter.

Answer (score 8):

*note: question was originally about a current limiter*

The [LM317](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317-n.pdf) with the single series resistor between output and adjust input is actually a fixed current source, not a current limiter. You don't need the LM317 to create a current limiter, a few discrete components will do:

[image]

For a limiting at 2mA you select a 330\$\Omega\$ resistor for \$R_{SENSE}\$. If there flows 2mA through it Q2 will start to conduct and reduce the base voltage of Q1, so that its current is cut off.

**edit** (re changed question)
Maybe you're focusing too much on the LM317. If you need a constant current you could use the [LM234](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm234.pdf) which is a programmable current source for up to 10mA. You set the current with a resistor.

Comment: OP changed his question. He now wants constant current, not current limiting, like he asked originally.

Comment: I actually need a constant current, not a limited current.  I've edited my question.

Comment: The LM234 looks like an good option.  I will look into that.

Comment: Will the LM234 compensate if the variable resistor in my circuit changes its resistance?

Comment: @Hesadanza: yes, that's what it's a constant current source for!

Answer (score 3):

Minimum operating current for an LM317 depends on the difference between input and output voltages.

[image]

Comment: The input voltage for my circuit will be about 2.755 V.

Comment: @Kellenjb The output voltage doesn't really matter, as long as I can maintain 2mA current.

Comment: @Hesadanza Edit your question. What you asked for in your question is constant voltage with a current limit. Explain that you want a constant current output. I am going to delete some of my previous comments since they are no longer relevant to your actual question.

Comment: True.  Sorry about that.  I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need the LM317 to do this. It sounds like what you want is a constant current source, which will force the same amount of current through a variable load (up to the limitation of the input voltage).

A basic way to do this is with a current mirror, which is shown below. 
[image: circuit]

Your input is on the left (V1 at 2.755V as you have specified). The reference of 2mA is set by a resistor Rref (it happens to be 1k, but it depends on your transistor and your input voltage, you can adjust it if you need more or less current). The current which goes through the reference resistor is mirrored onto the (variable) resistive load (which is designated Rload).

My version of SPICE does not really simulate potentiometers, but I have used a macro instead to simulate the resistance from 100 Ohm to 1 KOhm in 10 steps (100, 200, 300...1000 Ohms). The current through the load potentiometer is shown below. Different resistances are in different colors; it is small, but the scale on the left goes from 2.095  mA at 100 Ohm to 2.060 mA at 1 KOhm:
[image: iload over rload]
Notice that there is a small variation (on the order of several percent), but the current mostly stays around 2mA - even though the resistance changes by an order of magnitude.

You should look up the Wikipedia article on current mirrors as well. Clearly there is a limited range for which the current mirror will continue to give you 2mA; for example, if you make the load 10 KOhm, it will not work since the voltage across it will need to be 20 V alone (not counting any drop in the transistor).

Answer (score -1):

It's really simple to do that with a LM317 setup as a regulated constant current source. Vref. is 1.25 volts/625 ohms=2 mA. Use a 1k variable resistor on the output and adj. terminal. Adjust the current to whatever you like ;). http://www.reuk.co.uk/LM317-Current-Calculator.htm

You should have no problem with input-output voltage differential with a 2 mA load. 1x LM317, 1x 1kOhm Variable Resistor, 1x 0.1uF ceramic capacitor on the Vin to Gnd and you're good to go.

Comment: You should have no problem with input-output voltage differential with a 2 mA load. 1-LM317, 1-1k Variable Resistor, 1-.1uf ceramic capacitor on the Vin to Gnd and you're good to go ;).

Comment: The 317 needs 10mA of output current to regulate properly!

Comment: @Frederico Russo: I've heard that before and the LM334 seems genuinely superior for low currents but I don't see that result with the 317. I'm using the 317t recently and all I get is a rock steady 2.38 milliamp output. Granted that's with the meter attached in series and in place of the intended load rather than in series with it but what's the worst case here? (I mean assuming nothing shorts.)

Comment: You can go around the minimal current requirement by adding a resistor between the output pin of 317 and ground. Nothing changes in the current sensing feedback loop.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
[This Schematic as a PDF](http://flowstateengaged.com/img/kickstarter-images/public-schematic.pdf) is possibly what OP is after.

An [LM334Z](https://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM134.pdf), with a 33 ohm resistor and 12v gives 2 mA.

Comment: What kind of a schematic is that? What's that IC shape? And the LED is reversed. And the 12V is not a requirement, the current is independent of that.

Comment: @stevenvh - thanks for the grumpy comments.  The cct diag is not mine, it's from a group aiming to make and sell these devices.  Please show where you mention an LM334z (hint, you don't.)  The LED is not reversed, learn to read (bad) cct diagrams.

Comment: I mention the LM234. If you would take a look at the LM334's datasheet, you'd see that it lists LM134, LM234 and LM334. They're the same devices, they're all three current sources, just a different temperature range. And the LED *is* reversed, unless you're used to connect the cathode to the plus (I don't). The reversed 12V will kill it. I *can* read schematics, I've done it for 30 years, thanks.

Comment: I've added a link to the datasheet. Have a look at it, it's interesting :-). It's a good habit to do so for uncommon ICs you refer to. And about the grumpy comment: you're welcome :-).

Comment: Holy shitballs, those fruitcakes are literally hooking that thing up to wet sponges stuck to their head! It looks like typical new-agey batshit insanity based on extrapolation from one research paper somewhere. Judging from how badly they drew the schematic, I don't doubt that their device be similarly engineered, and wind up killing someone. Hopefully they get sued over it.